# IE 7 main div is not shown

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

On my website (http://rochiidevis.com/rochii/detalii_rochie/1304?showback=true) the main div is not shown in ie7. Do you know why I have this issue? I tried to use 
Developers Toolbar ... but I could not find the cause for this.

Any help is more than welcomed.

Comment: what is the id/class of div which is not shown in ie7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 has a weird bug in which floated elements dissappear, I have found a nice way to remedy this is to add `zoom:1;` to the parent objects of floated elements

if you do a

```
 * {zoom:1;}
```

it should fix things

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed my issue. It would have taken me days to figure out this.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `height: 0;` from `.clear`.

Comment: it also fixes the issue ... but I feel it is not the right approach.

Comment: The .clear is already empty, so why change the height? I never had the need to do that.

Comment: I would not change the css of the theme that works in all major browsers ... I will just apply the zoom fix in the ie_fix.css. In this way I will reduce the impact. I am not good at all at css :(

Comment: I would like the one tat downgrade the answer to provide a comment for that. Maybe it is obvious ... but not for me:)